# Which is proper form?

Tags: php

PHP.

```
$a['0']=1;
$a[0]=2;
```

Which is proper form?

Comment: Next time try choosing a better title. Something like: "Which is the proper syntax for array assignment in php?"

Comment: Really? You're nitpicking the title??? wow

Answer (score 8):

In the first example you use a string to index the array which will be a hashtable "under the hood" which is slower. To access the value a "number" is computed from the string to locate the value you stored. This calculation takes time.

The second example is an array based on numbers which is faster. Arrays that use numbers will index the array according to that number. 0 is index 0; 1 is index 1. That is a very efficient way of accessing an array. No complex calculations are needed. The index is just an offset from the start of the array to access the value.

If you only use numbers, then you should use numbers, not strings. It's not a question of form, it's a question of how PHP will optimize your code. Numbers are faster.

However the speed differences are negligible when dealing with small sizes (arrays storing less than <10,000 elements; Thanks Paolo ;)

Comment: I think you are overstating the speed differences here. Yes the first one is slower but not drastically or at any sort of level that is making it remotely relevant to an application unless you are doing hundred of thousands of permutations.

Answer (score 4):

In the first you would have an array item:
   Key: 0
   Index: 0

In the second example, you have only an index set.
   Index: 0

```
$arr = array();
$arr['Hello'] = 'World';   
$arr['YoYo']  = 'Whazzap'; 
$arr[2]       = 'No key';  // Index 2
```

Comment: In your example there are no indexes 0 and 1, so it's better to eliminate those comments.

Comment: I thought it would be auto-indexed to <the biggest index> + 1 ?

Comment: there is no "auto indexing" unless you use the $arr[]= syntax.

Answer (score 4):

The "funny" thing is, you will get exactly the same result.
PHP (for whatever reason) tests whether a string used as array index contains only digits. If it does the string is converted to int or double.

```
<?php
$x=array(); $x['0'] = 'foo';
var_dump($x);

$x=array(); $x[0] = 'foo';
var_dump($x);
```

For both arrays you get [0] => foo, not ["0"] => foo.

Or another test:

```
<?php
$x = array();
$x[0] = 'a';
$x['1'] = 'b';
$x['01'] = 'c';
$x['foo'] = 'd';
```

foreach( $x as $k=>$v ) {
  echo $k, ' ', gettype($k), "\n";
}

```
0 integer
1 integer
01 string
foo string
```

If you still don't believe it take a look at #define HANDLE_NUMERIC(key, length, func) in zend_hash.h and when and where it is used.

You think that's weird? Pick a number and get in line...

Comment: Yes, but try $x['0']='foo'; $x[0]='bar';

Comment: Exactly my point. $x['0']='foo'; $x[0]='bar'; var_dump($x); --> [0] => string(3) "bar"

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to increment your keys use the second option. The first one is an associative array which contains the string "0" as the key.

Answer (score 1):

They are both "proper" but have the different side effects as noted by others.

One other thing I'd point out, if you are just pushing items on to an array, you might prefer this syntax:

$a = array();
$a[] = 1;
$a[] = 2;
// now $a[0] is 1 and $a[1] is 2.

Answer (score 0):

they are both good, they will both work.

the difference is that on the first, you set the value 1 to a key called '0'
on the second example, you set the value 2 on the first element in the array.

do not mix them up accidentally ;)